# Launch Bootstrap modal on page load in a React based site.

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I need to load a page and as soon as it loads pop up a modal with some info for the user. I have tried this using the standard:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

However, that does nothing. I think it doesn't work because of the way React loads and uses a virtual DOM. (I could be wrong on this)

But is there a way to launch a bootstrap modal on page load in React?

Answer (score 4):

Call the modal in the Life Cycle Method of the component you are trying to mount, (`componentDidMount()`, to do it when it's already mounted, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand correctly but If you are using Reactjs then I think you should use a library that implement bootstrap in a react way, maybe [React bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io) or [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io)

Import the library and use the Modal component the library gives you, and just pass the right property to show the Modal.